# How would you create a ring of cells in flutter?

Tags: flutter, custom-painting

I would like to create a widget (I know it must be a CustomPainter) to draw something like this:

[image]

Notice that there are n concentric cell circles. 
The main problem is that I need to access/paint each of this cells when needed to repaint it in different colors. I have been checking the CustomPainter canvas class and the only thing that could fit my needs is the draw arc thing. But, I can't provide a width for the arc (I tought I could draw a draw for every cell).

My last resort is using an image/sprite that would represent a cell. This way I could duplicate and transform it along a circle path to obtain something like the image. But I don't like the idea.

Has anybody accomplished this before in flutter?

Comment: I would consider learning how to create a dashed line first. Then you can use the painter to create a dashed circle. You can then iterate further and play with thicknesses. 

Consider this package as a starting point. I had to create something similar, however, I cannot share the code due to work

https://github.com/ajilo297/Flutter-Dotted-Border